# WPF binding viewmodel to multiple views using datatemplate

Tags: wpf

I am successfully using a ResourceDictionary to tie my viewmodels to views, but i am not able to tie the same viewmodel to two different views.

Heres my code so far:

resourcedictionary XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1" DataType="{x:Type domain:MyViewModel}">
        <views:MyView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2" DataType="{x:Type domain:MyViewModel}">
        <views:MyOtherView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

View XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
             xmlns:i= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
             Content="{Binding MyViewModel}"
             ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource Template1}">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is clearly completely wrong as I am now getting the xaml error "UserControl.Content has been set more than once", and green lines under the grid.

I then tried removing the Content property of UserControl which lets it build but of course also not bind to the viewmodel.

So how am i supposed to set the content correctly using datatemplate keys?

Comment: The UserControl.ContentTemplate defines the visual content of the UserControl MyView. Now when you take a look at your DataTemplate, you can realize that the DataTemplate itself contains the templated control MyView. This can't work. You should provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a binding of the same viewmodel to two different views. Maybe this is a stupid thing to try, I have no idea.

Comment: But how do you show this views? You usually use a DataTemplate to dynamically show a view based on the data model. What you are trying to do sounds like you simply should assign/bind the "same" (same instance? Same class?) view model to the DataContext of the relevant views e.g. MyView1 and MyView2.

Comment: Your example view is named "MyView" - same name as the control inside of Template1. Is that a posting error or is this your current code?

Comment: Anyway, to remove the exception, you would have to remove the UserControl's content. You do this by deleting the Grid. The elements between the UserControl tags are implicitly added to the Content property. So you are setting the Content property _implicitly_ by adding UI elements and _explicitly_  by setting a data binding on the Content property.

Comment: But since you are adding the UserControl MyView to itself (as mentioned before) you will create a infinite loop here. This usually creates a new exception: StackOverflow. Probably after fixing the fisrt exception. But I still don't know your mission.

Comment: this is my code yes.. and yes everything about it is completely wrong. I just have two different views, one which is able to open the other, and they should share the same viewmodel so I have access to the same properties. I also tried the datacontext route but also unsuccessfully because my second view is a window and it has a seperate visual tree i guess and i have no way of accessing the datacontext to set it on the new visual tree. I dont know if this is the correct terminology, this is just stuff visual studio is telling me.

Comment: but yea setting the viewmodel to two different views is probably the wrong path to take... I think i am lacking some basic understanding of what is going on so i think i will leave it at that

Comment: If your second view is a Window then the DataTemplate approach won't work. The DtaTemplate contet is inserted into an existing visual tree while a Window always is the root of its own visual tree. You can for example define the instance of your shared view model in App.xaml. Then bind it to both controls using StaticResource on the DataContext property.

Comment: i am not sure how you would define that in App.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `Content` property twice.

When you add an UI element between the tags of a `ContentControl` (`UserControl` is a `ContentControl`), then this element is implicitly assigned to the `Content` property. In your example `Grid` is implicitly assigned to the `Content` property of `MyView`. At the same time you explicitly assign the `Content` property by setting up a data binding on `MyView.Content`.

The solution to get rid of your exception is to remove either the `Grid` or the binding on the `Content` property. This will fix your exception, but will lead directly to a new exception.

By assigning the view model to the `Content` property, while having a `DateTemplate` defined for the `ContentTemplate` property, you instruct WPF to add the content of the `DataTemplate` to the `Content` of your `UserControl` (`MyView`). Since `MyView` is the templated control and at the same time it is also the content of the `DataTemplate`, you basically are trying to add `MyView` to the `Content` of `MyView`. This results in an infinite loop, because as soon `MyView` is added to `MyView` it will add another third `MyView` to the second `MyView` and so on. It is easy to predict that this will lead to a `StackOverfloException`.

What you may want is to bind the same instance of your view model to multiple controls.

For this one, the solution is to add an instance of the shared view model to the global *App.xaml* ResourceDictionary and reference it from there using StaticResource:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModel" />
  <Application.Resources>
<Application>
```

**View 1**

```
<Window DataContext="{StaticResource SharedViewModel}">

</Window>
```

**View 2**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{StaticResource SharedViewModel}">

</UserControl>
```

Note that creating an instance of your view model in XAML requires your view model to have a parameterless constructor.
Also keep in mind to use the instance defined in *App.xaml* throughout your application (whenever you need to reference the same view model). So you would have to delete your previous view model assignment (e.g. `DataContext = new ViewModel()`).

Comment: when the instance of the viewmodel is created in a class that handles all viewmodels, how am i able to define it like this in app.xaml?

Comment: i think this produces a new viewmodel right?

Comment: You can always add objects like a shared view model to _App.xaml_ using `Application.Current.Resources.Add("SharedViewModel", viewModel);`. This way you only have a single instance referenced throughout your application. As this would work there might be better or other solutions in general. You have not provided much details to give you a more tailored solution. But the solution I have provided will work for sure.

Comment: yea i can accept your answer, but i dont think i will be able to get it to work in my project. At this point i am feeling a bit hopeless about programming in general

Comment: I can't help you with your programming skills. I can help you to solve your problem if you would provide more details that narrow down your actual issue. You should explain what you _really_ want and how your application looks like e.g. wher your DataContext comes from and where you instantiate your view models. And why you think this won't work for you. How can we know your code and application flow like what class áor view instantiates what class or view.

Comment: To improve your skills you need to know more about WPF. Your current issue seems to be more related to the lack of knowledge regarding the WPF framework. You can read [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to understand the idea of templates in WPF.

Comment: [Overview of XAML resources (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)